# How to get last modified date of file

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to get the last modified date of a file and this turns out to be more complicated than I thought. My first attempt was this:

```
hFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
GetFileTime(hFile, &creationTime, &lastAccessTime, &lastWriteTime);     
FileTimeToSystemTime(&lastWriteTime, &t);

printf("TEST: %d %d %d\n", t.wHour, t.wMinute, t.wSecond);
```

I've tested this with a file on my HD whose last modified date is reported by Explorer as Friday 21st March, 1997, 14:34:58. Now with the code above I got the same date except that the time is reported as 13:34:58, i.e. one hour off. So I thought this is probably related to missing timezone/DST adjustments so I added a call to `FileTimeToLocalTime()`, i.e. like this:

```
hFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
GetFileTime(hFile, &creationTime, &lastAccessTime, &lastWriteTime);
FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&lastWriteTime, &ft);               
FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &t);
```

But now the time is reported as 15:34:58, i.e. still one hour off but now in the opposite direction. So I still don't get the 14:34:58 as reported by Explorer.

That's why I'd like to ask how I can get the last modified date as reported by Explorer. Anyone?

Comment: Does it work with a file you created today?

Comment: Yes, it does. Strange.

Comment: I guess it's because the older file is from before daylight saving time.

Comment: Probably, but Explorer shows it correctly so I'm wondering how I can get the same result as Explorer.

Comment: [Why do Explorer and the command prompt interpret file times differently?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130308-00/?p=5023)

Comment: As pointed out in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-filetimetolocalfiletime#remarks), **use the following sequence of functions** in place of using `FileTimeToLocalFileTime`: 1. `FileTimeToSystemTime`
2. `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime`
3. `SystemTimeToFileTime`.  Can you have a try?

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks, it's true. When using `dir` from `cmd.exe` it indeed shows the same time as I get with the second code snippet in the OP. So the issue described my Raymond Chen is exactly what I'm seeing here.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT: Yes, that works, feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: @Andreas Glad to hear that. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog "[Why do Explorer and the command prompt interpret file times differently?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130308-00/?p=5023)" address the reason for why you get different last modified time of a file from Windows API and from Explorer: "**Daylight Saving Time**".

To account for **daylight saving time** when converting a file time to a local time, use the following sequence of functions in place of using [`FileTimeToLocalFileTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-filetimetolocalfiletime#remarks):

1. FileTimeToSystemTime
2. SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime
3. SystemTimeToFileTime.